# Android: Increase the touch area of Navigation icon in the toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, drawerlayout

I want to increase the touch area of the navigation icon (Drawer icon or Up button) in the Material toolbar like it was in Kitkat. I tried to add padding to the icon but that actually shifts the title to the right. So I dont want any change in the position of the title or the navigation icon, just the touch area should be wider. Please help.

Comment: Is there a way to add the click listener to the title as well? So click the button or the title opens the drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<style name="myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
</style>
```

And apply to your Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The suggested solution scales up the navigation icon to a huge size. Has someone else tried to do this? Please help.